# Theme sublime text 3

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите название темы для sublime text 3 (как на скриншоте)

Answer (score 0):

По моему это стандартная тема для Submlime Text - Monokai, шрифт только не стандартный

Comment: Нет, у monokai шрифт какой-то розовый

Comment: Шрифт можно изменить отдельно от темы

Comment: Там же не только белый цвет, а еще и зеленый, светло-коричневый

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать поиск по картинке. И ещё откуда источник скрина? Если из своего саблайм, почему не просмотреть Preferences>>>Settings?